# Set tikz labels with a for-loop from an array

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a bunch of nodes in tikz, where the i-th node should be labeled with the i-th string (either math or text) in an array.

For example, if I have the array

```
\def\array{{$X$, $Y$, $e^{x+z}$, $p$, $t$, $q$}}
```

I'd like to generate

```
\node[label={$X$}] (0) at (0, 0) {};
\node[label={$Y$}] (1) at (3, 0) {};
\node[label={$e^{x+z}$}] (2) at (6, 0) {};
\node[label={$p$}] (3) at (9, 0) {};
\node[label={$t$}] (4) at (12, 0) {};
\node[label={$q$}] (5) at (15, 0) {};
```

but using a for-loop instead, as in my actual use case the array is much larger. I'd be tempted to do something like:

```
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 5} {
    \node[label={\array[\i]}] (\i) at (3\i, 0) {};
```

but this does not work. What is the proper way to do this?

I could see in other questions that the `evaluate` function can be useful in case the labels are to be evaluated as arithmetic, but this is not my case.

More in general the context would simply be something like:

```latex
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\array{{$X$, $Y$, $e^{x+z}$, $p$, $t$, $q$}}
            \foreach \i in {0, ..., 5} {
                \node[label={\array[\i]}] (\i) at (3\i, 0) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to be more explicit. What exactly is unclear now?

Comment: You have to enclose the entries by " because they are strings: `\def\array{{"$X$", "$Y$", "$e^{x+z}$", "$p$", "$t$", "$q$"}}` (and can drop the `$` if you use `label={$\array[\i]$}`), or just loop over the list,  `\foreach \myentry in {$X$, $Y$, $e^{x+z}$, $p$, $t$, $q$} {...}`. I'd also use `\myarray` instead of `\array`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). That you for including a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301).  For future reference, please check that your code does not have basic compile errors as is currently the case. Also, please do edit the question to correct the  current [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301).  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can step through your array and also have a counter to compute the positions:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \def\array{$X$, $Y$, $e^{x+z}$, $p$, $t$, $q$}
     \foreach [count=\i] \x in \array {
            \node[label={\x}] (\i) at (3\i, 0) {};
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! In order to recreate the desired output I think it should be `[count=\i from 0]`.